# Android spinner set item activity launch

Tags: java, android, android-intent, spinner

I have 2 activities in my android application, Activity A which has a List View of objects that when I click displays the details of that object in Activity B. Activity B is the same activity in which objects are added in the first place with a basic input form layout.

I am receiving the information about an object from Activity A using .getSerializableExtra()
from an Intent in Activity A.

I can retrieve the data correctly for my edit texts such as the name variable which is input using an edit text :

```
et_medicationName.setText(med.getMedicationName());
```

But cannot work out how to do the same for my Spinner ?

So I set the spinner item, along with other fields, on Activity B and save the object which appears in my list view on Activity A (as the Title only) but how do I retrieve the selected spinner item when I click a List Item on Activity A to view it again in Activity B.

Here is my Serializable code which may be of use:

```
Serializable currentMed = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Med");
    if(currentMed != null)
    {
        Medication med = (Medication)currentMed;
        et_medicationName.setText(med.getMedicationName());

        //Get Medication Type from selected Spinner item here? 
    }
```

I also have a getter/setter set up for the spinner.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition("Stringvalue"));

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks

```
Spinner spinnername1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String mStr = spinnername1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

**For Pass Value into Intent**

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("Value", mStr);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

**For Getting Value from Intent.**

```
Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
String mValue = bdl.getString("Value");
```